# Find $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(n-\sum_{k=1}^n\cos{\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

How can I calculate the following limit:

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(n-\sum_{k=1}^n\cos{\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n})}$$

A hint or direction would be appreciated (please not a solution for now, I would post mine once I get it).

I have tried to use 3rd order of taylor but I couldn't get through with the algebra.

Thank you

Comment: Hint : $1-\cos(\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n})\sim \frac{k}{n^2}$ ... (since $k\leq n$)... What do you think of $\sum_n  \frac{k}{n^2} $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that using Taylor series to first term, you get

$$n-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n}\approx\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{2 n^2} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} xdx = \frac{1}{4}$$

Alternatively you can use $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: "(please not a solution for now"... But it is a nice use of my hint...

Comment: Sorry did not read!!

Comment: I have not studied integrals and the use of this notation: $\approx$. Can you explain?

Comment: What does it mean? How did you make that transition?

Comment: Mister - next term you get is of the form $\frac{\sum k^2}{4! \cdot n^4}$ where numerator is third degree polynomial, so this term also vanishes. Starting at this term, all terms have lower degree poynomial on numerator than denominator..

Comment: Why does it vanish? It's a sum so it doesn't go to zero

Comment: Second term: $\frac{\sum k^2}{4! n^4} = \frac{(n)(n+1)(2n+1)}{6 \cdot 4! \cdot n^4}$ which goes zero as n goes large

Comment: Got it. That's why you can omit the remainder?

Comment: Yeah! And Then numerator degree cannot keep up with denominator degree rising

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$$n-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\cos\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n}\right)=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^2 \frac{\sqrt{k}}{2n}$$
and $\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n}\in(0,1)$. You may consider that $\sin^2 x = x^2+O(x^4)$ and that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{4n^2}=\frac{1}{8}+o(1),\qquad \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^2}{16n^4}=o(1).$$